# Interface Builder flips Landscape/Portrait

Tags: interface-builder, landscape, portrait, landscape-portrait

This is a pretty frustrating issue - and I have no idea what's causing it.

I am working on an app that is in Landscape mode.
When I create a new UIViewController file and open up its xib, it starts off as Landscape.

Then, as soon as I set the Status Bar from 'black' to 'none' - the orientation dropdown still says Landscape, but the View's dimensions change from 1024 x 648 to 748 x 1024.

Has this happened to anybody before?
Any ideas what is causing it?

My solution every time this happens is to delete the .h/.m/.xib and try again by creating a new file. Eventually I'll get a .xib that doesn't automatically flip its orientation on me.